# How can I run an ionic app in a browser having Cordova DatePicker plugin?

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, automation, protractor, cordova-plugins

common.js:290 Native: tried calling DatePicker.show, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

Comment: I guess Native plugins won't work on browser you need to check on device/ emulator.

Comment: @Amarendra, It is highly recommended to use actual physical device to test the native plugins.